# what is the difference between Space-based computing and Cloud computing

Tags: cloud, spaces

I am new to the Cloud Computing world. So I yet to learn too many things about cloud computing. Yesterday, I was watching a video pod cast on space-based programming and through out the session, I felt that the whole concept of spaces sounds similar to cloud computing. After the session, I searched the web for understanding the difference between the space based computing and cloud computing. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any better answer. Hence thought of posting this question.

Can somebody help me to understand what is the difference between space based computing and cloud computing?
OR
How space based computing is related to cloud computing?

Comment: In space, no one can hear you crash :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud computing refers to the hosting of applications on a large data center, that allows the application to use as much of the provided computing power as needed for any given time. Different cloud computing providers (e.g. Google or Amazon) provide different APIs for the hosted applications.

Space based computing on the other hand, is not so much about the hosting, but more about the communication of components of a distributed system. The "space" is basically a centralized data channel through which distributed components publish and consume data. This is supposed to simplify distributed application concerns (transaction handling, reliable communication, etc.) when components do not need to interact directly with each other.

An application running on a cloud platform is (almost certainly) accessible via the Internet. That is not necessarily the case with space based computing.

Comment: That was a real simple and clear explanation. Thank you so much. With the answer above, is it correct if I assume space based computing and Grid computing are almost the same?

Comment: Grid computing and space based computing are similar in that computing resources are loosely coupled (grid computing uses middleware to take care of the intercommunication). The main difference is that with space based computing there are typically distinct components communicating via the "space", whereas with grid computing there are not always distinct components involved. With grid computing there are many parts of a larger program/computation distributed among many computers.